# Disable right click on a specific div

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution to disable right click over a specific div. I have this code that does this, but it also display an alert (i fixed this) and it works on the whole page.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
//Disable right mouse click Script
//By Oscar Frank
//For full source code, visit http://www.oscarmini.com
var message="";
///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
return false;
}
}
function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
return false;
}
}
}
if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
// -->
</script>
```

Can someone help me make this work only one or more specific divs? Thanks! I am a noob.

Comment: Just dont try this. There are a million workarounds to this and it is absolutally user UNfriendly.

Comment: Thanks mjsoft. This helped me. And thank you all

Answer (score 13):

On the div that you are trying to disable right click events, you can just add this:

```
oncontextmenu="return false;"
```

Example:

```
<div oncontextmenu="return false;">This div won't have the right click menu</div>
```

Comment: But you shouldn't do this kind of behaviour, since it breaks user experience.


[https://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/](https://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an event on the specific div ( you can get the div by id document.getElementById ) and add an event listener for contextmenu. 
Example:

```
    document.getElementById("divId").addEventListener("contextmenu ", function(){
       console.log("Right Click");
       return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is disable right mouse click in specific div as I understand.
You can use the jQuery plugin for that. Here is the code that you can refer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{
          border: 2px solid black;
          height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
    This is the Phone and NO ONE SHOULD RIGHT CLICK THIS! >:) 
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#demo').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        return false;
    }); 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP doesn't need a jQuery solution.